# Find number of triplets

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> How many triples of positive integers $(a,b,c)$ satisfy $a\le b\le c$
>   and  $abc=1,000,000,000$

I tried prime factorizing R.H.S. and solving equivalently, the equation $\alpha$ + $\beta$ + $\gamma$ =$9$ for positive integer solutions and multiplying it by two (as there are two prime factors each with power 9). For the restrictions I put $\beta$=$\alpha$+1 and $\gamma$=$\beta$+1, where $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ $\ge 1 $. Still my answer is coming out wrong. Is there any problem in my approach as I have checked my calculation and it seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 9$ you want nonnegative integers, not necessarily positive ones.  For any two (not necessarily distinct) solutions
$(\alpha_1, \beta_1, \gamma_1)$ and $(\alpha_2, \beta_2, \gamma_2)$ you can take
$a = 2^{\alpha_1} 5^{\alpha_2}$, $b = 2^{\beta_1} 5^{\beta_2}$, $c = 2^{\gamma_1} 5^{\gamma_2}$ (disregarding the ordering).  Of the solutions with $(a,b,c)$ distinct, one out of $6$ will have $a < b < c$.  But then you need to take into account the solutions with two of $(a,b,c)$ equal, one out of $3$ of which have $a \le b \le c$, and the one solution with $a=b=c$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What's the maximum value of a? --> How many values could a take on?

For each value of a, what's the maximum value of b? How many values could b take on?

For those values of a and b, what's the maximum value of c? How many values could c take on?